# Print values that are on one sheet but not on a second sheet

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I have three sheets:1) sheet 1; 2) sheet 2; 3) sheet 3.
I want to compare column A of sheet 1 and column B of sheet 2.

I want to print values, that are on sheet 2 but not on sheet 1, on sheet 3.

The code I wrote prints both common values and unique values on sheet 3.

```vb
Sub GetUniques()
    Dim data1 As Long, data As Long, merged As Long
    Dim i As Long
    data = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    data1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    merged = 1
    
    For i = 1 To data1
        Cells(merged, "E").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
        merged = merged + 1
    Next i
    For i = 1 To data1
        Cells(merged, "E").Value = Cells(i, "C").Value
        merged = merged + 1
    Next i
    
    Range("E:E").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 2):

If you have O365 you can use something like:

```
=LET(x,FILTER(Sheet2!B1:B1000,(Sheet2!B1:B1000<>"")* ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!B1:B1000,Sheet1!A1:A1000,0))),IF(x="","",x))
```

If you have Excel 2007+, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B1:B1000,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((Sheet2!B1:B1000<>"")*ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet2!B1:B1000,Sheet1!A1:A1000,0)))*ROW($B$1:$B$1000),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,1000)))),"")
```

In some versions you may have to enter this formula as an array over multiple rows with `ctrl`+ `shift` + `enter`; or use an `INDEX` function to display the individual elements of the returned array.

If you **must** have a vba solution, I suggest

- Read each column into a vba array (much faster than working to/from the worksheet
- create a dictionary `D1` with the unique entries from the Sheet1 column A
- create a 2nd dictionary of items from Sheet2 column B which excludes any items found in `D1` (or duplicate items from sheet2)
- output the results on sheet3

For example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub getUniques()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet, WS3 As Worksheet
    Dim V1 As Variant, V2 As Variant, vResults As Variant
    Dim D1 As Object, dResults As Object
    Dim V As Variant, I As Long
    
Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set WS3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

With WS1
    V1 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

With WS2
    V2 = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
End With

Set D1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    D1.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
    For Each V In V1
        If Not D1.Exists(V) Then D1.Add V, V
    Next V
    
Set dResults = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dResults.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
    For Each V In V2
        If Not D1.Exists(V) And Not dResults.Exists(V) Then dResults.Add V, V
    Next V
    
ReDim vResults(1 To dResults.Count, 1 To 1)
I = 0
For Each V In dResults.Keys
    I = I + 1
    vResults(I, 1) = V
Next V

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With WS3.Range("M1").Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vResults))
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vResults
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Elegant & helpful solutions :+) - *fyi posted an alternative approach demonstrating the `Match()` function equipped with a pair of arrays as arguments.*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the let function yet, you can use this formula in column c of your sheet 2. It will say "unique" if the value is not found in column a of sheet1 or sheet3 and duplicate otherwise.

Enter with control+shift+enter

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(B1,Sheet1!A:A)),ISNUMBER(FIND(B1,Sheet3!A:A))),"duplicate","unique")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Compare sheet columns via 2-array `Match()`**

> *I only want to print values that are on sheet 2 but not on sheet 1 ~> on sheet 3.*

I demonstrate a `Match()` comparison of two datafield arrays,
where `base` represents the values on sheet2, `comp` the column to be compared with on sheet1.

The resulting array is a mixture of found duplo indices and of `Error 2042` in case of non-findings,
thus revealing a base item as unique. So the final array can be filled with uniques by a simple loop
picking up only the unique items.

*Note that this example call references worksheets via the project's sheet Code(Name).*

```
Sub CompareSheetColumns()
'[1]get column data and assign them to arrays
    Dim base: base = getColRange(Sheet2, "B").Value
    Dim comp: comp = getColRange(Sheet1, "A").Value
'[2]compare both column values, where Sheet2 represents base data
    comp = Application.Transpose(Application.Match(base, comp, 0))
'[3]get uniques
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(comp)
        If IsError(comp(i)) Then    ' uniques stand out by Error 2042 instead of found index
            ii = ii + 1             ' increment uniques counter
            comp(ii) = base(i, 1)   ' get unique item
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve comp(1 To ii)    ' reduce to final count
'[4]write results to any target
    Sheet3.Range("M2").Resize(UBound(comp), 1) = Application.Transpose(comp)
    
End Sub
```

**Help function `getColRange()`**

*Returns 1-based 2-dim datafield arrays of given columns and slims down main code to make it better readable:*

```
Function getColRange(mySheet As Worksheet, _
                     Optional ByVal myColumn As Variant = "A", _
                     Optional ByVal Startrow As Long = 2) As Range
    With mySheet
        'a) get last row in given column
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, myColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        'b) return data range as function result
        Set getColRange = .Range(myColumn & Startrow & ":" & myColumn & lastRow)
    End With
End Function
```